# Why is my UI updated only once?

Tags: angularjs, signalr

I have done a simple SPA with AngularJS/signalR that send a notification to my hub Hello when the app starts.

On the client side I have list of notifications managed by a controller. This list got updated only once whereas I have been able to see that my callback is called every time thanks to the console.log (and the debugger shows that this.messages grows at every notification received).
I don't get why the UI only update on first call (which the one the current client have emittted)

Here is the code that work only once.

```
NotificationCtrl.prototype.hello =  function() {
        console.log("hello");
        this.messages.push(new Notification("Tom", "Now", "Is now connected"));
}
```

Comment: have you tried to add a `$scope.$apply` to see if it works ?

Comment: No, where should I put this line ? Furthermore I have started to use the "controller as" syntax and don't have $scope available.

Comment: I'd have said in the callback, but if you don't have a scope, it's gonna be difficult indeed :)

Comment: But I can revert it to use a regular controller with a $scope injected

Comment: You can try that just for this one variable.

Comment: Thanks that was my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `$scope.$apply` because the callback is not scope aware since its not called from angular.

I think you would benefit alot from my library called SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
Its designed around the Event aggregation pattern and is perfect for MV* enabled sites with Knockout or Angular.

Have a look at the wiki for setting it up
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Demo project
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Recent blog post I did about it
http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/05/27/client-server-event-aggregation-with-signalr/

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

Comment: It looks very interesting indeed. I planned to look at evaggretion in a second step but you kindly offer me a solution that solve my issue and clean it up. I will definitely have a look at it.